# TripleDES encrypting and decrypting gives strange results

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography

I have a working implementation of `TripleDESCng` (tested against some test vectors), but the following happens:

When I encrypt plain text `This is a sample message` (24 bytes, thus for this it would be 3 blocks) (hex for it is `5468697320697320612073616D706C65206D657373616765`) with an example key, I get `E81F113DD7C5D965E082F3D42EC1E2CA39BCDBCCBC0A2BD9`. However, when I decrypt this with the same example key, I get `5468697320697320612073616D706C650000000000000000`, which, when converted back to ASCII, is:

`This is a sample`.

Any reason other than my code why this would behave this way? To encrypt and decrypt, I use 24 byte keys (ECB mode).

EDIT:

```
using (var tripleDES = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider())
{
   byte[] data = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("This is a sample message");
   Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(data));
   tripleDES.IV = new byte[tripleDES.BlockSize / 8];
   var encryptor = tripleDES.CreateEncryptor();
   byte[] result = new byte[data.Length];
   encryptor.TransformBlock(data, 0, data.Length, result, 0);
   var decryptor = tripleDES.CreateDecryptor();
   byte[] result2 = new byte[result.Length];
   decryptor.TransformBlock(result, 0, result.Length, result2, 0);
   Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(result2));
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: The default mode is CBC, not EBC. Since you don't explicitly set the `Mode`, why do you think this is EBC? Plus it's 2018. Outside of historic interest, why are you writing *new* code that uses outdated ciphers and outdated modes?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever the mode is not a problem, IV is set to 0s either way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With almost all modes<sup>1</sup>, you should make sure that the final part of your data is pushed through [`TransformFinalBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.icryptotransform.transformfinalblock(v=vs.110).aspx) rather than `TransformBlock`<sup>2</sup>, to make sure it knows that no more data is coming and to ensure final blocks are flushed/written.

It's bad form, in general, to assume the output size is going to match the input size.

> the mode is not a problem, IV is set to 0s either way

Yes, that'll mean that the *first* block was not affected by your choice of Mode. But all *subsequent* blocks will be, because they will use the chaining mode and the previous block, *not* the IV. So if you *want* ECB (you shouldn't<sup>3</sup>) you need to explicitly set that mode.

---

<sup>1</sup>Your code is using CBC, not EBC as you claim in your narrative. CBC is the default mode for .NET encryption classes.

<sup>2</sup>And when using this second method, pay attention to it's return value, as mjwills commented.

<sup>3</sup>You've picked an outdated crypto algorithm, paired it with an outdated mode of operation, and your words I've quoted above mean that you don't understand modes. Added together, I would *suggest* that you're not well placed to be writing code that uses crypto currently. The .NET classes can make it seem easy to write crypto code but you still have to understand how to make good choices in using them. Better to spend more time on *researching* these things before writing code.

Comment: I was well aware the default mode is CBC. I'm sorry, but your suggestion seems to be based on vague assumptions about my knowledge and the choice of algorithm, which, by the way, I purposefully ignored, since I have my own reasons (don't worry, this code is not supposed to reach production)

Comment: the actual problem was with the final block indeed, I agree I should've studied it a bit more carefully, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem is in the method of the encryptor / decryptor that you are using: the TransformBlock method is conceived to transform a block when you will be encrypting multiple blocks.

That is not the case in your code, where you want to transform a single block, and therefore you should be using the TransformFinalBlock method instead. BTW I took the liberty of making your sample buildable.

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace Tests
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Security.Cryptography.TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tripleDES = new System.Security.Cryptography.TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("This is a sample message");
            byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("NOSTROMOHASSOMEGODPOWERS");
            tripleDES.Key = key;
            tripleDES.IV = new byte[tripleDES.BlockSize / 8];
            var encryptor = tripleDES.CreateEncryptor();
            byte[] result = new byte[data.Length];
            result = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
            string res = BitConverter.ToString(result).Replace("-","");
            Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(result).Replace("-",""));

            byte[] data2 = result;
            tripleDES.Key = key;
            tripleDES.IV = new byte[tripleDES.BlockSize / 8];
            var decryptor = tripleDES.CreateDecryptor();
            byte[] result2 = new byte[data2.Length];
            result2 = decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(data2, 0, data2.Length);
            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result2));
        }
    }
}
```